# apply masterpage to site collection and all subsites - SharePoint foundation 2013 using powershell

Tags: powershell, custom-masterpage

I'm working on a **sharepoint foundation 2013.**I have applied a custom masterpage on the root site the site collection.I would like all the subsites to inherit this masterpage and apply across all aistes.
How can i get this done using powershell as i don't want to have to do it individually.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you want to update master page in your site collection and there sites
I have update my code  in my answer second snippet code will work for you I have test it it work for me Let me know if you find any issue
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://sitecollectionrootUrl"    
$site = Get-SPSite $url    
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{   ##I have commented out the system master Url setting
    ##$web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/Mycustom.master";
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Mycustom.master";    
    $web.Update();    
    $web.Dispose();    
}
$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

For All Site Collection in your webapplication

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #Get All site collections
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All
    #Loop through all site collections
       foreach($Site in $SiteCollections)
        {
            #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
           foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
           {
$web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master";
$web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master";
$web.Update();
Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
           }
        }
```

Particular Site Collection

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://sp:1000/sites/Ex15
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master";
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master";
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to [loop through all the subsites](https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/powershell-to-loop-through-all-sharepoint-sites-and-pages/) and then set the value of the masterpage for each with the following code.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint

$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"

$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"

$web.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not require any powershell to apply the site collection master page on all subsites.

1. Go to Root site collection -- > **Site settings**--> **Master Page** (under Look and Feel).
2. Select your masterpage. Check "**Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting**" . Click Ok.

Now all your sub sites will inherit the masterpage of the root site.

Comment: Hi Unnie, thanks for the reply.
But no idea where those settings are...
Can you elaborate? Which SharePoint version are you talking about?

Comment: Foundation do not have publishing feature. This "inherit" thing should belong to publishing feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $site = Get-SPSite http://iddddp:100/
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
    $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/HMC_Master_IN.master";
    $web.Update();
    Write-Host $web.Url $web.MasterUrl $web.CustomMasterUrl;}
```